# Knockout js checkbox is not checked when setting selected values in the view model

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

My problem is when I set the values of the selected checkboxes through the viewmodel the checkboxes aren't checked until I click another checkbox.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selectedTags, attr: {value: '1', id: '1'}" /> 1
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selectedTags, attr: {value: '2', id: '2'}" /> 2
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selectedTags, attr: {value: '3', id: '3'}" /> 3

<button data-bind="click: alertMe">Click Me</button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function ViewModel () {
    var self = this;
    
    self.selectedTags = ko.observableArray([]);

    // I added 1 to the selected tags array
    self.selectedTags().push('1');
    
    self.alertMe = function () {
        alert(self.selectedTags());
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way of adding items to an `observableArray` is to call `push` directly on the `observableArray` (this way KO will be notified that your array was changed):

```
self.selectedTags.push('1'); //no () after selectedTags
```

In itself it won't solve your problem because you are setting the `value` of the checkboxes with the `attr` binding, and Knockout (before version 3.0) fires the bindings in order. So your `checked` binding gets executed first which does not find the values so it cannot set your checkboxes.

You can upgrade to knockout 3.0 to solve this or change the order of your bindings:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       data-bind="attr: {value: '1', id: '1'}, checked: selectedTags" /> 1
<input type="checkbox" 
       data-bind="attr: {value: '2', id: '2'}, checked: selectedTags" /> 2
<input type="checkbox" 
       data-bind="attr: {value: '3', id: '3'}, checked: selectedTags" /> 3
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QkPGK/).

Comment: thanks for the help and some lectures :) it was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Just edit HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selectedTags" value="1" id="1" /> 1
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selectedTags" value="2" id="2" /> 2
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selectedTags" value="3" id="3" /> 3

<button data-bind="click: alertMe">Click Me</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eHj5X/6/